# adf until activity and if condition activity

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

Looking for some guidance
I am building a pipeline which checks a condition using If- condition activity
If condition is true I am using until activity (inside the true section of If activity) to process my data transfer requirement

while debug I am getting this error
"code":"BadRequest","message":"Container activity cannot include another container activitynull","target":"pipeline/Pipeline1/runid/526d67ff-867c-432a-b449-b0e951f1c40","details":null,"error":null}

Any suggestion for above issue

Comment: As the error said, the Container activity cannot include another container activitynull. Can you tell us which condition you want to check? I think you can only use the until active instead of if condition.

Comment: @LeonYue  Thank you reply,  does that mean I can not use one activity inside another activity or it is only case with until activity

Comment: I think so. As I understand, If condition has the contained active(true or false active), the until active also have the container actives. Data factory doesn't support use nested if condition with until active.

Answer (score 1):

You can get around the limitations on nested activities within Azure Data Factory by wrapping your inner activities in another pipeline.

[image: Pipeline 1]

[image: Pipeline 2]

[image: Until Nested Within If]